# 3 questions on linear independence

Tags: linear-algebra

> Are the following linear independent?
>
> 1. If S $=$ {$a, b, c$} $⊆ R^3$, where $(2,3,4)$ $∉$ span {$a, b, c$}.
> 2. If S $=$ {$a, b, c$} $⊆ R^3$, where $(1,2,3)$, $(1,3,2)$, $(2,1,3)$, and $(0,1,0)$ $ϵ$ span {$a, b, c$}.
> 3. If $S = (u + v, u - v, u - 2v + w) ⊆ R^n$, where $(u, v, w) ⊆ R^n$ is a linearly independent set.

**My thoughts:**

From what I know, linear independent means there is only one solution.

As for question 1, what i understood by this $(2,3,4)$ $∉$ span {$a, b, c$} is that $$(2,3,4) ≠ \lambda_{1} a + \lambda_{2} b + \lambda_{3} c $$ where $\lambda$ are real numbers. What then does this relation means?

As for question 2, I was thinking along finding any form of linear combination between the four vectors and if it exists $\implies$ they are no linear independent. Am i right to say that? If so, what is the best way to find linear combinations.

As for question 3, I was thinking of forming linear combinations as well, but the additional vector w makes it impossible for me to work out a solution.

Please advice thanks.

Comment: I assume you're asking, in each case, if the set S is linearly independent?

Comment: It might help to know that if I have three linearly independent vectors $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}^{3}$, then $\text{span}(a,b,c) = \mathbb{R}^{3}$...

Comment: **Hint:** As $S$ contain three vectors of $\Bbb R^3$, note that $S$ is linearly independent if and only if it spans $\Bbb R^3$.

Answer (score 0):

Question $1:$ suppose that $S$ is linearly independent. Then $span(S)= \mathbb R^3$, hence $(2,3,4) \in span(S)$, a contradiction.

Conclusion ?

Question $2:$ show that the vectors $(1,2,3), (1,3,2)$ and $(0,1,0)$ are  linearly independent. Since they are in $span(S)$, we have $span(S)= \mathbb R^3$.

Question $3:$ Your turn:  $S$ is linearly independent. To this end show that the equation

$0=r(+v)+s(u-v)+t(u-2v+w)$ (with $r,s,t \in \mathbb R$)

has only one solution: $r=s=t=0$.